# android webview show youtube.com/tv video in fullscreen

Tags: android, webview, youtube, fullscreen

I am making an app for displaying youtube.com/tv on tv sets.
It has a simple and nice layout, and it also has some nice features like pairing and controlling it via a smartphone.
So..
I use webview to get url: youtube.com/tv

Everything works fine, exept I would like it to automatic show in fullscreen when a vid is selected.

Normally I have found all my answer searching, (here) but this one is hard.

I would like all to happen within the webview. That should be possible? Or do I need to start a new intent, or make a newclass videoview.java to call a eks. videoview.xml? Really unsure about this..
The reason I ask is that when a vid is started, youtube.com/tv automaticly plays next like a playlist, would love to keep it that way.

I found some document about HTML5 fullscreen at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowCustomView(android.view.View, android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback) on how to do this but still confused. Is that the way to go?
Using:

```
public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
```

And:

```
public void onHideCustomView ()
```

Here is my main TV.java Until now. Please be gentle as I am very new with this stuff.

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class Tv extends Activity
{
    WebView web;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Transparent actionBar Only option menu available...
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        setTitleShowHomeEnabled();
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        // webview id
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //webchromeclient
        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        //hide search bar
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        //Enable javascript
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        //Scale video controls
        web.setInitialScale(150);
        // Test

        //web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        //web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        //web.setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(true);
        //web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        //Load url
        web.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/tv");
        //Load file from assets NB: Missing "S" is correct
        // web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yt.html");
    }


    //Fullscreen
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
    {
    }

    public void onHideCustomView ()
    {
    }
    //End fullscreen


    private void setTitleShowHomeEnabled()
    {
    }

    private void setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean b)
    {
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack())
        {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    // Ask if user wants to exit
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                //Tv.this.finish();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
    }


    //Option menu
    public class SimpleOptionMenu extends Activity
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.text1:    
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); //Read Update
            alertDialog.setTitle("Information");
            alertDialog.setMessage("In order to log in to your account and activate the use of your smart phone, please select: -Sign in & settings- -> -Sign in- in the left menu, write down the activation code, and then click on -Activate- in this menu. Have a happy tube :) ");

            alertDialog.setButton("Continue..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    // here you can add functions
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
            break;

        case R.id.text2:   
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, GetActivation.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
            //Exit
        case R.id.text3: 
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); // <- Complete kill
            //Tv.this.finish(); <-Dosent kill totally
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```